# Create a rough "world overview" map with mkgmap

Tags: openstreetmap, garmin, basemap

I'm trying to generate a "World overview map" for my Garmin device. The idea is to have this map on the device all the time, for a very rough idea of the position and then feed in higher resolution maps where necessary, e.g. when going on trip. I would like to use OSM for this purpose with mkgmap.

If I do this straightforward, I would create a ridiculously large img-file, using all the OSM data. I would thus like to just have lower scale information included in the map. However I haven't grasped yet, how to achieve this. Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the whole planet file is just too big for mkgmap to process, so for a worldwide basemap you would be better off to filter the data before processing.

It might be a better idea to get a worldwide dataset from [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/) and convert it to OSM format for mkgmap processing. BTW the lower zoom levels of openstreetmap.org are **not** rendered from the database, but from Natural Earth as well.

Alternatively, you can take the [OSM coastline extract](http://openstreetmapdata.com/data/coastlines), and mix it with the Natural Earth `populated places` shapefile.

Comment: "BTW the lower zoom levels of openstreetmap.org are not rendered from the database, but from Naural Earth as well."
openstreetmap.org has different layers (currently 5). Each layer gets rendered differently. I suspect that at least the Humanitarian layer uses OSM data even for lower zoom levels.